# Best realistic story telling LLM?

Tags: llm, gpt, llama-2, text-generation

I've been using WizardLM-SuperCOT30bUncensored for quite some time now, and I'm wondering if there is anything better these days for stories? Because apparently this model is cool, but I can see that it's very defective sometimes (lack of common reasoning) - when in a story a character is e.g. badly injured, after 2 sentences LLM forgets about it and continues the story as if he was fine, it also often writes unrealistic scenarios (like that someone managed to escape from some trap, even though realistically he wouldn't have 1% chance, or that 1 man alone beats a herd of bears - completely unrealistic stories) Also, I'm looking for some LLM who will both be able to tell stories that are as close to reality as possible, but will also be able to minimally deviate from that if he writes a fantasy story, very well understand the cause and effect sequence, and the realities between the characters,. and have a strong knowledge of the world and processes, so as to avoid unknowingness and false information and actions in the story. Size does not matter, it can be and even 70B and above, as long as the requirements match. Also nice that LLM will have more knowledge about current events (pandemic, ukraine-russia conflict in 2022) I want answers and idk where to write it, on reddit I am blocked so i post there.

Answer (score 2):

Over the past two or three weeks, I've been experimenting with the evaluation of local LLMs in the areas of real-world knowledge and creative writing in particular.

In my testing, I've found that LLMs have the following problems when used for storytelling:

- A penchant for introducing improbable, absurd or contradictory plot directions (as noted in the question itself)
- Failure to follow prompt instructions
- Failure to produce dialogue, even when clearly instructed
- Inability to produce meaningful plots (LLMs seem to operate on paragraph-level or scene-level prose at best)
- Repetitive, cliched writing ("she couldn't help notice", "it sent shivers down their spines", etc.)

Let me *recommend* two models, one large(r) and one small:

- dolphin-2_2-yi-34b
- dolphin-2.2.1-mistral-7b

I believe Dolphin Yi outperforms WizardLM-Uncensored-SuperCOT-StoryTelling-30b. Depending on the use case, this may or may not turn out to be true, so it is hard to call any one model "the best".

Others I've tested, but ended up being less than impressed with:

- echidna-tiefigther-25 (sic!)
- opus-v0-7b
- Yarn-Mistral-7b-128k

I couldn't test 70b models as they require 64 gigs of RAM. That put aside, this is the size where inference speed starts to become a real problem.

I've used the following params: Temp=1, Top P=0.6, Top K=50. These are reasonable, but could be tweaked further.

Many of the above-mentioned shortcomings can be alleviated by regenerating the response 3-5 times, then picking the best parts and combining them into final prose. With that kind of workflow, inference speed matters, so fast turnaround might even give 7b models an edge.

For creative writing, local LLMs still have quite a bit to go.